# Covering space morphism maps each sheet onto some other sheet

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am considering a connected topological space $X$, with a connected covering space $Y$ and $p:Y \to X$. Is it true that given any continuous map $f:Y\to Y$ such that $p=p\circ f$, $f$ always maps a sheet **onto** some other sheet?

If not, under what conditions of $Y$ can we conclude this?